# IntelliJ 14.0.3 JavaDoc Urls not working

Tags: intellij-idea

How do you get JavaDoc URLs to work in IntelliJ?

I have added what I thought was correct, under "Project Settings", "Libraries" following JavaDoc URL:
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs

... but pressing Ctrl-Q in the editor on for example a Workbook method only gives me:

> Following external urls were checked:    http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createSheet(java.lang.String)    http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createSheet-java.lang.String- The documentation for this element is not found. Please add all the needed paths to API docs in Project Settings.

Testing above URLs work just fine, why can't IntelliJ show them then, is it not in correct format or what ?
I can ofc fire them up externally but was expecting them to show up in the popup (like the java 8 doc). Same goes for other external libraries that my project depends on.

Anyone else with the same problem or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132323

Comment: Thanks, did not see that. Hope they fix that in next update then